# Add event handler for body.onload by Javascript within <body> part

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onload-event

We want to include a maps from Google Maps API in our document. The documentation tells to initialize the map with a function called by the `onload()` event of the body.

The ordinary way to call:

```
<body onload="initialize_map();">
```

This doesn't work out for us because we're using `Template::Toolkit` and the `<body>` tag is already included in our wrapper. In short: The `<body>` tag is already printed when our Javascript code starts running.

I tried something like this but it does only work for `onclick`, not `onload`. I guess that's because the Javascript code is beneath the `<body>` tag itself.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

body.addEventListener("load", init(), false);

function init() {
        alert("it works!");
};
```

Any help how to fire up a Google Maps map appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we were already using jQuery for a graphical eye-candy feature we ended up using this. A code like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // any code goes here
    init();
});
```

did everything we wanted and cares about browser incompatibilities at its own.

Comment: There's also a somewhat simpler form of `$(function() { init(); });` available.

Comment: even simpler would be `$(init);`

Answer (score 47):

```
body.addEventListener("load", init(), false);
```

That init() is saying run this function now and assign whatever it returns to the load event.

What you want is to assign the reference to the function, not the result. So you need to drop the ().

```
body.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Also you should be using window.onload and not body.onload

`addEventListener` is supported in most browsers [except IE 8](http://caniuse.com/#search=addEventListener).

Comment: For IE it would be `attachEvent`. quirksmode.org describes it very well: http://quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: It sure is friendly now

Answer (score 46):

You should really use the following instead (works in all newer browsers):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: Why does this not work? `document.addEventListener('load', init, false);`

Comment: @Luke you should bind that event to the window as such: `window.addEventListener('load', init, false);`

Answer (score 19):

As @epascarello mentioned for W3C standard browsers, you should use:

```
body.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

However, if you want it to work on IE<9 as well you can use:

```
var prefix = window.addEventListener ? "" : "on";
var eventName = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
document.body[eventName](prefix + "load", init, false);
```

Or if you want it in a single line:

```
document.body[window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent'](
    window.addEventListener ? "load" : "onload", init, false);
```

Note: here I get a straight reference to the body element via the document, saving the need for the first line.

Also, if you're using jQuery, and you want to use the `DOM ready` event rather than when the body `load`s, the answer can be even shorter...

```
$(init);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply wrap the code you want to execute into the onload event of the window object:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: There are 2 potential problems with this approach.  1) You over-write any other onload events that may have been attached, and 2) onload may have already fired depending on where you put this code, and as a result may never fire