# phonegap build Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

Building a Phonegap Build app and have suddenly run into a weird problem.  I get the following error in Chrome inspect:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined`

This is my code:

```
        function onLoad(){

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        }
```

Indeed inside of onDeviceReady the first thing I do is `alert("hello");` and I never see the alert.

Here's the caller:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Comment: What you have wouldn't throw a ReferenceError. Only *calling* onLoad with the function not in scope would cause that. Are the function and your call in the same scope?

Comment: The indentation says that `onLoad` is defined within another function (or is it just bad formatting?). Are you sure the caller can access the scope where `onLoad` was declared?

Comment: @Robusto edited to include the caller.

Comment: Your `onLoad()` **must** be available before the DOM finishes loading.

Comment: do you have a content security policy meta tag in your index.html?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling your "onLoad" function from the markup. If your scripts are not loaded by that point then the function will indeed throw an error.

A better way to do that would be to add an event listener to the window and run your script when the onload is triggered there.

See [Add event handler for body.onload by javascript within <body> part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082165/add-event-handler-for-body-onload-by-javascript-within-body-part) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the onLoad function isn't at the same scope from where it's being called. Who is calling the "onLoad" function?

Comment: Are you wrapping that piece of code in a <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> tag?

Comment: Yes, it's wrapped in script tags.

Comment: It was supposed to work... this is exactly what you want http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html ,

Comment: That's exactly what I have.  Literally, the only difference is that I have code in onDeviceReady instead of it being empty.

Comment: Could you send me your code? Maybe i can help you better