# JavaScript function not running on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I'm trying to adapt a JS file that parsed JSON data from a Google Spreadsheet into a format used for printing labels to a Dymo printer. The script looks like this:

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  $Id: GoogleSpreadSheet.js 38773 2015-09-17 11:45:41Z nmikalko $ 
//
// Project -------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  DYMO Label Framework
//
// Content -------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  DYMO Label Framework JavaScript Library Samples: 
//    Print mulltiple labels using Google Spreadsheet as a data source
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Copyright (c), 2010, Sanford, L.P. All Rights Reserved.
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------



(function() {
  var label;
  var labelSet;

  function onload() {
    var printButton = document.getElementById('printButton');
    var printersSelect = document.getElementById('printersSelect');

    function createLabelSet(json) {
      console.log('starting to parse the JSON for the labels');
      var labelSet = new dymo.label.framework.LabelSetBuilder();

      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {

        var assetID = assetID[i];

        console.log(assetID.id);


        var assetID = assetID[i];
        var staffName = staffName[i];
        var serialNumber = serialNumber[i];
        var assetTag = assetTag[i];

        var address = assetID + '\n' + staffName + '\n' + serialNumber + '\n' + assetTag;

        var record = labelSet.addRecord();
        record.setText("Address", address);
      }

      return labelSet;
    }

    function loadSpreadSheetDataCallback(json) {
      labelSet = createLabelSet(json);
    };

    window._loadSpreadSheetDataCallback = loadSpreadSheetDataCallback;

    function loadSpreadSheetData() {
      removeOldJSONScriptNodes();

      var script = document.createElement('script');

      console.log('starting to create the new elements');

      script.setAttribute('src', 'getLabelsJSON.php?');
      script.setAttribute('id', 'printScript');
      script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);

      console.log(script);
    };

    function removeOldJSONScriptNodes() {
      var jsonScript = document.getElementById('printScript');
      if (jsonScript)
        jsonScript.parentNode.removeChild(jsonScript);
    };
    // create address label xml
    function getAddressLabelXml() {

      var labelXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
                            <DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
                             <PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
                             <Id>Address</Id>\
                             <PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
                             <DrawCommands>\
                              <RoundRectangle X="0" Y="0" Width="1581" Height="5040" Rx="270" Ry="270" />\
                             </DrawCommands>\
                             <ObjectInfo>\
                              <AddressObject>\
                               <Name>Address</Name>\
                               <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
                               <BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
                               <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
                               <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
                               <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
                               <IsVariable>True</IsVariable>\
                               <HorizontalAlignment>Left</HorizontalAlignment>\
                               <VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment>\
                               <TextFitMode>ShrinkToFit</TextFitMode>\
                               <UseFullFontHeight>True</UseFullFontHeight>\
                               <Verticalized>False</Verticalized>\
                               <StyledText>\
                                <Element>\
                                 <String>DYMO\
                                        828 San Pablo Ave Ste 101\
                                        Albany, CA 94706-1678</String>\
                                                            <Attributes>\
                                                                <Font Family="Arial" Size="12" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                                                                <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
                                                            </Attributes>\
                                                        </Element>\
                                                    </StyledText>\
                                                    <ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>False</ShowBarcodeFor9DigitZipOnly>\
                                                    <BarcodePosition>AboveAddress</BarcodePosition>\
                                                    <LineFonts>\
                                                        <Font Family="Arial" Size="12" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                                                        <Font Family="Arial" Size="12" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                                                        <Font Family="Arial" Size="12" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
                                                    </LineFonts>\
                                     </AddressObject>\
                                     <Bounds X="332" Y="150" Width="4455" Height="1260" />\
                                  </ObjectInfo>\
                             </DieCutLabel>';
      return labelXml;
    }

    function loadLabel() {
      // use jQuery API to load label
      //$.get("Address.label", function (labelXml) {
      label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(getAddressLabelXml());
      // }, "text");
    }

    // loads all supported printers into a combo box 
    function loadPrinters() {
      var printers = dymo.label.framework.getLabelWriterPrinters();
      if (printers.length == 0) {
        alert("No DYMO LabelWriter printers are installed. Install DYMO LabelWriter printers.");
        return;
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i) {
        var printer = printers[i];
        var printerName = printer.name;

        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = printerName;
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(printerName));
        printersSelect.appendChild(option);
      }
    }

    // prints the label
    printButton.onclick = function() {
      try {
        if (!label)
          throw "Label is not loaded";

        if (!labelSet)
          throw "Label data is not loaded";

        label.print(printersSelect.value, '', labelSet);

        //                var records = labelSet.getRecords();
        //                for (var i = 0; i < records.length; ++i)
        //                {
        //                    label.setObjectText("Address", records[i]["Address"]);
        //                    var pngData = label.render();
        //
        //                    var labelImage = document.getElementById('img' + (i + 1));
        //                    labelImage.src = "data:image/png;base64," + pngData;
        //                }
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message || e);
      }
    };

    loadLabel();
    loadSpreadSheetData();
    loadPrinters();

  };

  function initTests() {
    if (dymo.label.framework.init) {
      //dymo.label.framework.trace = true;
      dymo.label.framework.init(onload);
    } else {
      onload();
    }
  }

  // register onload event
  if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", initTests, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", initTests);
  else
    window.onload = initTests;

})();
```

The DYMO.Label.Framework can be found at:

http://www.labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.2.0.2.js

I need the `createLabelSet(json)` to run as that parses the JSON in a loop, but that doesn't appear to be running. I added a log entry:

```
console.log('starting to parse the JSON for the labels');
```

but I'm not seeing this in the browser console. I'm fairly new to JavaScript so not quite sure why this function isn't running when the page is loaded?

**EDIT:**

Changed the last line from `}());` to `})();` but still don't get anything in the console - not the `starting to parse the JSON for the labels` entry that should appear.

Comment: Where is dymo.label.framework

Comment: @Amit this can be found at `http://www.labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.2.0.2.js`

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: I am getting "No DYMO LabelWriter printers are installed. Install DYMO LabelWriter printers."

Comment: @lumio no console errors. just the 'starting to create the new elements' entry

Comment: @Amit you might have to have the Dymo printer driver installed unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but where are you calling `loadSpreadSheetDataCallback()`?

Comment: @freginold in this line `window._loadSpreadSheetDataCallback = loadSpreadSheetDataCallback;` I presume - wasn't my script and trying to understand how it works and debug at the same time

Comment: @user982124 That just assigns the function to that variable name; it doesn't actually invoke it.

Comment: This is not a window default event. window._loadSpreadSheetDataCallback

Comment: I'm getting a script error (in IE11) when trying to add in the Dymo script and run it... anyone else get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the expected output is because your `onload()` function is never called.  There are several ways you can have that function run on page load; [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839075/5463636) does a good job of describing some of them.

For example, adding this line to your code would execute the `onload()` function when the page is loaded:

```
window.addEventListener("load", onload, false);
```

MDN has a [good quick overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) of the `load` event, if you want to read up on it.

Comment: In original script the `loadSpreadSheetData` function was setting the `src` attribute to this URL: 
`http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/tSaHQOgyWYZb6mUPGgrsOGg/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=window._loadSpreadSheetDataCallback` Would adding the `&callback=window._loadSpreadSheetDataCallback` be the key here to getting this to load?

Comment: That could do it; it looks like the syntax fits.