# Unable to play audio automatically but if manually click a button, it works

Tags: javascript

I try this example which works only when I click the button. But when I try to call the playAudio method automatically (when the page load), it doesn't work. I have commented out the code.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");

function playAudio() {
  x.play();
}

// Doesn't work
playAudio();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <audio id="myAudio">
        <source src="media/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

  <p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

  <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>

</body>

</html>
```

I google for the error and tried below solution but still doesn't work.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var promise = x.play();
if (promise) {
  //Older browsers may not return a promise, according to the MDN website
  promise.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: I put the html code in the body tag and the javascript at the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add event handler for body.onload by javascript within <body> part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082165/add-event-handler-for-body-onload-by-javascript-within-body-part)

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any errors or used the browser developer tools to check events?

Comment: Some browsers now prevent audio from starting automatically and require that it be triggered by an action from the user. What you describe sounds consistent with that.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body onload=‘playAudio()’>
Body
</body>
```

Comment: No. I need to call it from Javascript.

Comment: Why? This will call your JavaScript method.

Comment: I need to programatically call the method from JavaScript. This method will not be called during page load all the time. it is just for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `<body onload="playAudio()">`